# How to avoid restart of Revit

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

I have programatically assigned a shortcut to my app using the Revit API.
The shortcut key is not reflecting unless I restart Revit 2015.
How can I avoid restarting Revit?  Is there any way so that after assigning the shortcut key I do not have to restart Revit 2015?

Comment: How have you assigned the shortcut key? I assume that you've modified the XML file directly, seeing as there's no official API to manage shortcut keys?

Comment: i have first read the xml from path then i assigned shortcut through my UI.shortcut is getting reflected in xml, but its effect is getting reflected only revit is started

Answer (score 0):

By directly modifying the XML file, there is no way for Revit to register the changes without a restart. You would need to use some form of UI Automation to modify the shortcuts using Revit's standard interface if you want the changes to be available immediately.